# If matrix $A-I$ is positive semidefinite, does $\lambda_{\inf} \geq 1$ hold?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-semidefinite

If matrix $A-I$ is positive semidefinite, does the following hold?

$$\lambda_{\inf} \geq 1$$

where $\lambda_{\inf}$ is the infimum of the set of all eigenvalues of $A$. If so, why?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**: Suppose you had an eigenvector $v$ with corresponding eigenvalue $\lambda$. What does $\langle (A-I)v,v\rangle\ge 0$ tell you?

Comment: Do you even need to suppose that $\lambda < 1$? Does it not follow straight from $\langle (A-I)v,v\rangle$?

Comment: Yes, fair enough. I'm guilty of the unnecessary contradiction proof for which I used to criticize my students. :) I'll edit, thanks.

Comment: Thanks! The quadratic form need to be nonnegative, implying $\lambda\geq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\lambda^\star$ be an eigenvalue of $A-I$.  Because $A-I$ is positive semidefinite, $\lambda^\star\ge0$.

The characteristic equation of $A-I$ is $$|\lambda^\star-(A-I)|=|(\lambda^\star+1)I-A|=0$$ and the characteristic equation of $A$ is $$|\lambda I-A|=0$$.

We have $$0=|\lambda I -A |=|(\lambda^\star+1)I-A|$$
so the set of eigenvalues of $A$ are in one-to-one correspondence with the set of eigenvalues of $A-I$,

and $\forall j\in\{1 ,\cdots ,\text{number of columns of }A\}$, $$\lambda_j = \lambda_j^\star+1$$
Let $\lambda=\min \lambda_j$ and $\lambda^\star = \min \lambda^\star_j$
$$\lambda^\star \ge 0,$$ $$\lambda^\star +1 \ge 1,$$
$$\lambda \ge 1.$$  All of the eigenvalues of $A$ are greater or equal to $1.$